# How do I express x(n)=n*0.9^n in scilab?

Tags: arrays, matrix, scilab

I'm trying to make a vector with function `x(n)=n*0.9^n`.

But there is a dimensional error on the following scilab code:

```
n = [0:1:100]; //samples
N=size(n,'*'); //number of samples

a= n * exp(n*log(0.9));
```

I know that `n * exp(~)` means multiplication between two 1 X 101 matrices.

How can I express this function properly?

Comment: What you post is not valid MATLAB code. Please don’t use the MATLAB tag if you don’t use MATLAB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do this like the following as `n` is a vector:

```
a = n .* exp(n * log(0.9))
```

Or

```
a = n .* (0.9 .^ n)
```